# Entering in large dollar values into rails money object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, money-rails

I have built an application running rails 4.1 and ruby 1.9.3 that uses the [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) gem. I'm encountering an issue when I input large dollar values into form fields and save them to my PG database. The error is the following:

```
PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: value "9900000000" is out of range for type integer
```

The [PG docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) show the max value of an integer being +2147483647. I would like to be able to use the money-rails gem but be able to enter larger numbers.

As far as a solution goes, I understand that the column type in PG should be a bigint, however I'm not how to enable money-rails to support storing numbers as bigint instead of integers.

Comment: I always thought `money-rails` was for dealing with intricacies like cents.  If you have huge numbers, maybe you could skip using the gem and just manipulate in whole dollars stored as `bigint`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in the [money-rails README](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#configuration-parameters) it shows that you can configure it to use other data types:

```
# Default ActiveRecord migration configuration values for columns:
#
# config.amount_column = { prefix: '',           # column name prefix
#                          postfix: '_cents',    # column name  postfix
#                          column_name: nil,     # full column name (overrides prefix, postfix and accessor name)
#                          type: :integer,       # column type
#                          present: true,        # column will be created
#                          null: false,          # other options will be treated as column options
#                          default: 0
#                        }
```

Notice there's a `type: :integer` option. Try changing that to `:bigint`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Will I need to remove and re-add all my migrations for these changes to take effect?

Comment: I think so. First do `rake db:rollback` and run the money-rails gem's rake task to install it again.

Comment: After trying that, I'm receiving an error `add_column("amount_requested", :bigint, {}) StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: undefined method to_sym` amount_requested is the first column that I'm using the add_money helper on.

Comment: That `add_column` call is missing the table name as the first argument. It should be: `add_column :name_of_your_table, :name_of_column, :bigint`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar question recently (with ruby 2.0 & rails 4.1). The only thing that was required is creating migration to support 8-byte integers, i.e. bigint:

```
 change_column :order_items, :unit_price_cents, :integer, :limit => 8
```

And it just worked. I my case I needed to support also 4 decimals, so I had to recreate USD currency as follows:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.register_currency = {
     :priority            => 1,
     :iso_code            => "USD",
     :iso_numeric         => "840",
     :name                => "United States Dollar with subunit of 4 digits",
     :symbol              => "$",
     :symbol_first        => true,
     :subunit             => "Subcent",
     :subunit_to_unit     => 10000,
     :separator           => ".",
     :delimiter           => ","
  }
end
```